How the evil spirits (exclubing Asuras and Rakshasas), were created?
Everyone knows about the evil spirits (ex. Bhuta, Vetala and etc). But, how they are originated? Does any scriptures mention it?

They originated from Lord Brahma during creation. You can refer to Shrimad Bhagavatam 3.20 (Conversation Between Maitreya and Vidura).
> सृष्ट्वा भूतपिशाचांश्च भगवानात्मतन्द्रिणा । दिग्वाससो मुक्तकेशान्
> वीक्ष्य चामीलयद् द‍ृशौ ॥ ४० ॥


The glorious Brahmā next evolved from his sloth the ghosts
and fiends, but he closed his eyes when he saw them stand naked with
their hair scattered.
Ghosts and mischievous hobgoblins are also the creation of
Brahmā; they are not false. All of them are meant for putting the
conditioned soul into various miseries. They are understood to be the
creation of Brahmā under the direction of the Supreme Lord.

